# tls wrapper over plaintext tcp

Tags: proxy, ssl, tcp, tls

is there any tool I can make tls forwarder over raw tcp?

I have a server which has no encryptions, purely plaintext tcp comunications.

I wanna connect to it over tls but cannot change the server code.

I need a tls forwarding tool to create a tls wrapper in server and forward to a plaintext tcp server.

if I connect to that tls, that tls connects to the plaintext server and acts like a proxy for me.

is there any free tool to make my life easier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is known as a "reverse proxy" or "termination proxy". Since you're specifically using it to provide TLS, it can be called a "TLS termination proxy" or "TLS offloading proxy". People commonly use nginx or HAProxy for this, but I'm sure there are as many solutions as there are HTTP server implementations. You could even use Python's built in HTTP server module to do this from a simple Python script.

The basic steps are to install the software you're going to use as the proxy, generate the TLS certificate you want your proxy server to use, install that cert into your proxy software, and configure the proxy software to forward all requests to the IP address and port of your insecure HTTP server.

If you use a self-signed cert you'll have to tell your clients to trust it. If that's a problem, you could use a service like Let's Encrypt to get a publicly signed cert that most clients will automatically trust.

Comment: ok, so fortunately it can be done. but can you provide me a clear example of using the simplest one?

Comment: @user3840019 I feel like I answered your question as written, but now you're moving the goalposts and asking for a tutorial or something. If you want to ask for a tutorial, you might be best off marking this current question as resolved, and then asking for a tutorial in a separate question (although SuperUser is more of a Q&A site and not so much a "please write me a tutorial" site). Tutorials for doing all the steps I mentioned already exist.

Answer (score 0):

as Spiff answered the question properly but didn't provide a clear example I myself found the easiest solution ever made in mankind history using [gost](https://v2.gost.run):

simply run the below command:

```
gost -L tls://:listen_port/:forward_port
```

in my case:

```
gost -L tls://:443/:80
```